# Error converting a 3 tiered nested list to ndim numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I have already gone through similar questions on the forum, but did not find anyone solving my query.

I have a list x_train as follows:

```
len(x_train)
Out[90]: 20000

len(x_train[0])
Out[91]: 1000

len(x_train[0][0])
Out[92]: 300
```

All the elements of x_train have already been made into equal length elements.

When I try to convert it to ndim array as follows :

```
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 1000, 300))
```

It gives me error as below :

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 20000 into shape (20000,1000,300)
```

How do I convert the list into desired shape array.

Comment: `x_train = np.array(x_train)`. `reshape` is made to work on arrays, not lists. You should first convert your list to an array using `array`. After that you shouldn't even need to reshape.

Comment: That resgape first does `np.array(x_train]`.  What's the `shape` and `dtype` of that?  I suspect the sublists aren't all the same size.